# Why does Zend Studio look and feel like Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

I just downloaded a demo of Zend Studio and it looks remarkably like Eclipse. I was wondering if they were built on top of the same libraries or if the developers just stole the look and feel to make it more user friendly on developers familiar with Eclipse.

If they are built off the same libraries or framework, which ones? I ask cause I'm interested if their is an IDE builder. A way to quickly create your own IDEs for instance. Thanks

Comment: The information can lead to a framework, set of libraries, or technology that can be researched for anyone interested in creating an IDE that looks like Eclipse. Bunch of trolls on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend Studio is built off of Eclipse, that's why it looks similar.  From [the Zend Studio website](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/):

> Zend Studio is the most up-to-date PHP
>   IDE that supports the latest
>   technologies such as PHP 5.3, Zend
>   Framework, and the latest Eclipse
>   Platform (Helios) ensuring your
>   environment is always up to date with
>   the latest advancements. You can also
>   use Zend Studio to easily build rich
>   PHP-based Ajax applications thanks to
>   extensive JavaScript support.

You can find a [list of other Eclipse-based software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Eclipse-based_software) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Oh right, the power of modularity and extendability. Thanks for the wikipedia list.